# Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : \\ Error occurred during initialization of VM agent library failed to init: instrument

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testng

Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Users\rahul.m2\repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.10/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument

@java, @maven @TestNG @eclipse || OS == windows ||
I'm facing this problem,

I even tried reinstalling everything(java / maven / eclipse)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKafm.png)
also tried deleting all files -> .m2\repository and updating the maven project (forced), but it still didn't work.

can anyone please help me?

Comment: Delete that directory `C:\Users\rahul.m2\repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/` and rebuild on plain command line ...check your settings.xml file configuration of checkSumPolicy....

Comment: hello, @khmarbaise ..!!

Comment: I tried ur steps,  now i'm getting 

An internal error occurred during: "Launching Test01_Get".
org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Answer (score 0):

idk is it actual now but i found solution. change aspectj.version to an earlier version (for example: 1.9.5) in dependencies and properties.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).